# How to let a middle view fill remain height (if any) inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, responsive-design, android-navigationview

For example,I want a 500dp and a 150dp TextView inside a LinearLayout. For responsive layout, at their middle, there would be a red area if there is any remaining height (e.g.:at large screen device):

Large Screen:

[image]

and if there is no remain space (e.g.:at small screen device), there would be no red area and the view become scrollable:

Small Screen:

[image]

I tried:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:background="#FFFFAA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:text="500dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
            <View
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:background="#AAFF"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:text="150dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

which set layout_weight="1" for the red area, but the red area does not fill the remaining height at large screen:

Large screen:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**make your scrollview like this**

use `android:fillViewport="true"` because it **Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.**

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:background="#FFFFAA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:text="500dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
        <View
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:background="#AAFF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:text="150dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `android:fillViewport="true"` on `ScrollView`. This will stretch content to the height of scroll view if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fixed footer

**Something like this:-**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:menu="@menu/drawer">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer_item_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Footer Item 1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer_item_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Footer Item 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And res/menu/drawer.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_item_1"
        android:title="Nav Item 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_item_2"
        android:title="Nav Item 2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_item_3"
        android:title="Nav Item 3" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_item_4"
        android:title="Nav Item 4" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/footer_spacer_1"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/footer_spacer_2"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="" />
</group>
</menu>
```